# How to convert ANSI format file to Unicode

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, ansi

I have one file that is encoded in ANSI format (showing in Notepad++ as Encoded in ANSI) and it also shows the special characters (degree celcius,pound etc.) and while reading i want to convert all the characters to unicode.

How can i convert ANSI to Unicode in C/C++ or Qt ?

Comment: What is `ANSI` encoding? Is it ISO-Latin-1 ? Maybe you could try `iconv` command on Linux?

Comment: Basile: ANSI refers to the legacy 8-bit encoding on Windows. Text files are often not Unicode but instead in that encoding, making them not very portable between systems. It's no specific encoding because it varies with the language and locale settings. On US or Western European machines it's usually codepage 1252, though. But you can set it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Qt is still very rusty, but something along the following lines:

```
QFile inFile("foo.txt");
if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QFile outFile("foo.out.txt");
if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
    return;

QTextStream in(&inFile);
QTextStream out(&outFile);
out.setCodec("UTF-8");

while (!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    out << line;
}
```

Pieced together from the documentation of [`QFile`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html) and [`QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html), both of which include examples for reading and writing files. The default for `QTextStream` is to use the legacy encoding, so we only need to set an explicit encoding on the output `QTextStream`.

If the file isn't too large you could probably also use

```
out << in.readAll();
```

instead of the loop over the lines. The loop especially might add a trailing line break to the output file (although the docs aren't very clear on that).

Comment: Why the `setCodec("UTF-8")` ? The default codec is `codecForLocale`, which happens to be the correct one in this case ("ANSI").

Comment: Because they want Unicode, not ANSI. For *reading* the default codec is sufficient, but not for writing. Hm, seems I misunderstood the question in that they only need an in-memory representation. Then the whole file writing stuff would be superfluous.

Comment: @MSalters Especially if you get files saved on Windows (with Notepad for example) but need to process these on Linux, such conversion is often necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

http://geekswithblogs.net/dastblog/archive/2006/11/24/98746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just read it with `QTextStream`. It will apply `QTextCodec::codecForLocale`, which uses the default ("ANSI") translation of 8 bits characters to Unicode.

Note that this won't work if you've copied an ANSI text file to Mac or Linux, as they don't have the notion of ANSI. For them, the ANSI text file will be ASCII-like so you should first convert to Unicode (UTF-8) and then copy.